# Problems with iterating over a string

Tags: python, string, integer, iteration, multiplication

I have a string of numbers I'm trying to iterate through. Say for example the string is 20 characters long, I'm trying to find the product of the first 5 numbers, then the second 5, the third, and so on.

So far I have converted the number to a string, then used an iterating index to produce the numbers I want to find the product of as strings.

I've then split the strings of numbers into an array of characters, then converted the characters to integers. I've then used a function to find the product of those numbers, then add it to an array.

The idea is that once I have the full array, I can find the largest of the products.

**The problem I'm having is that after the first iteration, the product is coming back as 0**, when it should be much higher.

My code looks like this:

```
def product(list):
    p = 1
    for i in list: 
        p *= i
    return p

products = []
count = 1

testno = 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969835203127745063262395783180169848018694788518438586156078911294949545950173795833195285320880551112540698747158523863050715693290
startno = 0
endno = 13

end = (len(str(testno)))-1
print("the end is",end)
while count < 4:
    teststring = (str(testno))[startno:endno]
    print("teststring is", teststring)
    strlist = (list(teststring))
    print("strlist is", strlist)
    numlist = list(map(int, strlist))
    print("numlist is",numlist)
    listproduct = (product(numlist))
    print("listproduct is",listproduct)
    products.append(listproduct)
    print("products is now",products)
    startno = startno + 1
    endno = endno + 1
    print("startno is now", startno)
    print("endno is now", endno)
    count += 1

print("the list of products is", products)
print("the biggest product is", max(products))
```

I have not done this as elegantly as I wanted to, perhaps because I don't properly understand the problem.

The offending output I'm getting looks like this:

```
the end is 999
teststring is 7316717653133
strlist is ['7', '3', '1', '6', '7', '1', '7', '6', '5', '3', '1', '3', '3']
numlist is [7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3]
listproduct is 5000940
products is now [5000940]
startno is now 1
endno is now 14
teststring is 3167176531330
strlist is ['3', '1', '6', '7', '1', '7', '6', '5', '3', '1', '3', '3', '0']
numlist is [3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0]
listproduct is 0
products is now [5000940, 0]
startno is now 2
endno is now 15
teststring is 1671765313306
strlist is ['1', '6', '7', '1', '7', '6', '5', '3', '1', '3', '3', '0', '6']
numlist is [1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6]
listproduct is 0
products is now [5000940, 0, 0]
startno is now 3
endno is now 16
the list of products is [5000940, 0, 0]
the biggest product is 5000940
```

I would be most grateful if someone could explain to me what is going wrong, how I can rectify it, and if there are any more elegant ways I could solve this problem.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where the product is 0, there's also a 0 in numlist. Multiplying by zero gets you zero.

Comment: `it should be much higher` no. I think you should reconsider the definition you put into the term `product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Axtract, Just modify your `product` function to below.

```
def product(list):
    p = 1
    for i in list:
        if i == 0: # Just use this if check here
            pass
        else:
            p *= i
    return p
```

Answer (score 0):

The product of zero and any number is always zero.

Notice that when your `numlist` has a zero, the product is zero.

Your first iteration doesn't have a zero, which is why you have a nonzero product.

Answer (score 0):

You have zeros in your products. The first one happens not to contain a zero, but all the others do.

So, your function is working properly --- just a problem with the input data.